# how to auto resize of childerin in horizontal stackPanel WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, desktop-application, titlebar

I try to build a title bare like **Google Chrome title bar** in WPF

I made the following
[image]

```xml
 <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!--taps -->
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="0">
            <!--open taps-->
            <local:TitleWindowTap  />
            <local:TitleWindowTap  />
            <!--add tap button-->
            <Button Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignIconButton}">
                <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="AddCircle"/>
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>

        <!--window control buttons-->
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="1">
            <Button Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignIconButton}" >
                <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="WindowMinimize"/>
            </Button>

            <Button Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignIconButton}" >
                <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="WindowMaximize"/>
            </Button>

            <Button Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignIconButton}" >
                <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="WindowClose"/>
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

and the code for the `TitleWindowTap` is a userControl as following

```xml
<Border Margin="5 5 0  5"  BorderBrush="{DynamicResource SecondaryHueMidBrush}" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="10">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignIconButton}" Grid.Column="1">
                <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="WindowClose"/>
            </Button>
            <TextBlock x:Name="txtBlock" d:Text="very long title bla bls" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="5" FontSize="20" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis">
                    no title
            </TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
```

### problem

when I add a new tap (manually in XML) it over the window controls like the following
[image]

### My question

how to auto resize this taps to fit the available space ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the taps to be auto-resized you should get rid of the `StackPanel` and use a `Panel` that actually resizes its children. You could for example add a `ColumnDefinition` per `TitleWindowTap`:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <!--open taps-->
    <local:TitleWindowTap  />
    <local:TitleWindowTap Grid.Column="1"  />
    <!--add tap button-->
    <Button Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignIconButton}">
        <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Circle"/>
    </Button>

    <!--window control buttons-->
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="3">
        <Button Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignIconButton}" >
            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="WindowMinimize"/>
        </Button>

        <Button Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignIconButton}" >
            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="WindowMaximize"/>
        </Button>

        <Button Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignIconButton}" >
            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="WindowClose"/>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use **ItemsControl** and its **ItemTemplate** and **ItemsPanel**. What you really want works nicely via **ItemsSource** binding to **ObservableCollection**<*YourDataType*>. Most likely you will need to have the "add" button as part of your data collection, but with another **DataTemplate**.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <!--taps -->
    <DockPanel Grid.Column="0">
        <!--open taps-->
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:TitleWindowTap />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Rows="1" Columns="{Binding Items.Count}" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
        <!--add tap button-->
        <Button Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignIconButton}" 
                Click="Button_Click">
            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="AddCircle"/>
        </Button>
    </DockPanel>
```